# How to capture Exceptions from threads I have no direct access to?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have developed a Windows Service capable of running a few plugins. Due to its nature, when developing Windows Services, the Start and Stop methods should run and return as fast as possible. The `Start` method runs `Start` methods from all plugins, which also should not block the execution. In this example, both plugins instantiate a Threading.Timer, which run in background.

The execution order happens as follows. The arrows indicate what runs in a different thread:

```
-> MyService.Start -> pA.Start -> pb.Start -> return
                          \_> DoWork()  \
                                         \_> DoWork()
```

Since both `DoWork()` are running inside a Timer, if an Exception happens, I am unable to catch it. This could easily be avoided if I could modify PluginA and PluginB, but I can't.

Any suggestion on what I could do to avoid this issue? Thanks in advance.

The following code is an oversimplification of the real code:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    private PluginA pA = new PluginA();
    private PluginB pB = new PluginB();

    // Windows Service runs Start when the service starts. It must return ASAP
    public void Start()
    {
        // try..catch doesn't capture PluginB's exception
        pA.Start();
        pB.Start();
    }

    // Windows Service runs Stop when the service Stops. It must return ASAP
    public void Stop()
    {
        pA.Stop();
        pB.Stop();
    }
}

// I have no control over how this is developed
public class PluginA
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(
            (e) => DoWork(),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        File.AppendAllText(
            "C:/log.txt",
            "hello" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
    }
}

// I have no control over how this is developed
public class PluginB
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(
            (e) => DoWork(),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        File.AppendAllText(
            "C:/log.txt",
            "Goodbye" + Environment.NewLine);

        throw  new Exception("Goodbye");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the exceptions *handled* by those plugins?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen they could be, if I enforced the developers to do so. But, since I am developing the Windows Service, I am attempting to ensure that even if a developer makes a mistake, I am able to recover from this mistake, instead of crashing the whole application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Please note that you can't recover from such an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Indeed, I was able to capture the Exception, but I wasn't able to keep the application running.  If there isn't a way of recovering from such an exception, how do applications like Visual Studio prevent a plugin from crashing the whole application?

Comment: Run it in a separate process.

Comment: Indeed, you can run the plugins in a separate process, then monitor it via a [wait handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit).  You can also make the process return an error code on error which you can examine and see if the process terminated properly, or faulted with an exception.

Comment: @Nick thank you. I have re-implemented the application using processes.